# Линковка со сторонней библиотекой

Tags: mingw, cmake, sfml

Проект `cmake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(projectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_definitions(-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE)

set(SFML_DIR /3dprt/)

include_directories(${SFML_DIR}/include/)
link_directories(${SFML_DIR}/build/lib/)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp window.cpp include/window.h)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    set(SFML_LIBS sfml-audio-s sfml-graphics-s sfml-main sfml-network-s sfml-system-s sfml-window-s)
else()
    set(SFML_LIBS sfml-audio-s-d sfml-graphics-s-d sfml-main-d sfml-network-s-d sfml-system-s-d sfml-window-s-d)
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBS})
```

Вроде бы все хорошо, но при попытке использовать заголовочные файлы из [sfml](/questions/tagged/sfml) на этапе компиляции mingw падает с криками о не слинкованных функциях/классов.

`SFML` собрал статически на этой же версии `MinGW`.

При попытке выполнить сборку, `MinGW` не удается найти библиотеки.

Что необходимо сделать дабы статические библиотеки слинковались?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В какой папке лежат эти библиотеки?

Comment: Относительно проекта `path/to/project/3dprt/build/lib/`

Comment: Попробуйте так: `set(SFML_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/3dprt")`

Comment: Да, это сработало, но библиотеки так же не линкуются.

Comment: Попробуйте полные имена библиотек с "lib" и ".a"

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `link_directories()` не рекомендуется, вместо этого нужно передавать абсолютные пути до библиотек в `target_link_libraries()`. Чтобы удобнее их составить, можно воспользоваться `file(GLOB ...)` или `find_library()`.

Ко всему прочему, сам sfml предоставляет модуль для нахождения его библиотек. Попробуйте `find_package(SFML COMPONENTS ...)`. Подробнее в [документации к модулю](https://github.com/SFML/SFML-Game-Development-Book/blob/master/CMake/FindSFML.cmake).

Comment: `Предупреждение CMake на CMakeLists.txt: 6 (find_package):
   Найденный файл конфигурации пакета:

     C: / Program Files (x86) /SFML/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake

   но он установил SFML_FOUND в FALSE, поэтому пакет «SFML» считается НЕ
   НАЙДЕННЫЙ.` :) Это после выполнения `install`

Comment: Документация говорит `If SFML is not installed in a standard path, you can use the SFML_ROOT CMake (or environment) variable to tell CMake where SFML is.`

Comment: Не помогает, CMake пишет что все хорошо, но при линковке все валится...

Comment: Покажите текст ошибки.